# Как скопировать сообщение и использовать parse_mode HTML для этого сообщения?

Tags: python, aiogram

Делаю рассылку.

Нужно что бы бот копировал сообщение через message.copy_to дополнительно с parse_mode html.

Пробовал:

```
await msg.copy_to(chat_id, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Возвращает то же сообщение, а мне нужно что бы в html конвертировалось.
Пример:

```
-<b>ыы</b>

(бот)-<b>ыы</b>
```

А нужно:

(бот)-**ыы**

Нужно copy_to так как могут отправлять разные типы данных дополнительно.

Реализовано ли это или нужно делать в ручную?
Изменено: await bot.copy_message(chat_id, msg.chat.id, msg.message_id, parse_mode="HTML") 1 в 1